# Creating containers inside a container throws error "docker: not found"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm automating the process of creating Docker images from simple ML models. 
So far I'm doing it successfully from a flask I'm which call is running in Linux
and has the templates to create the new containers from the models.

Now the next step if to containerize this API, I tried just creating the container and
calling the API but I get this error:

```
"docker: not found"
```

So basically, the docker container has not docker installed, hence I can not create new images from there.

I thought on installing Docker there and find some resources to do it:  https://github.com/jpetazzo/dind
But long story short: It is a bad idea.

From another blog, I found this: http://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/

"Do you really want Docker-in-Docker? Or do you just want to be able to run Docker (specifically: build, run, sometimes push containers and images) from your CI system, while this CI system itself is in a container?"

Which it seems to be a solution to my problem here, the blog proposes to use the volume flag to have exposed the socket:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...
```

which I did:

```
sudo docker run  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  -d -p 5100:5100 my_container:latest
```

But I'm getting the exact same error: "docker: not found" after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use [offical Docker dind](https://github.com/docker-library/docker/blob/92d278e671f32a9ee4a3c0668e46a41f4a3b74b0/19.03/dind/Dockerfile), instead of using this as [jpetazzo/dind](https://hub.docker.com/r/jpetazzo/dind/) which is not updated from last one year.

**Start a daemon instance**

```
$ docker run --privileged --name some-docker -d \
    --network some-network --network-alias docker \
    -e DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR=/certs \
    -v some-docker-certs-ca:/certs/ca \
    -v some-docker-certs-client:/certs/client \
    docker:dind
```

If you are interested to add some own binaries then

```
From docker:dind
# add here and create your own image
```

**TLS**

> Starting in 18.09+, the dind variants of this image will automatically
>   generate TLS certificates in the directory specified by the
>   DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR environment variable.

You can further read more about offical dind image [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker)

Data store:

> The Docker documentation is a good starting point for understanding
>   the different storage options and variations, and there are multiple
>   blogs and forum postings that discuss and give advice in this area. We
>   will simply show the basic procedure here for the latter option above:

Create a data directory on a suitable volume on your host system, e.g. /my/own/var-lib-docker.

Start your docker container like this:

```
$ docker run --privileged --name some-docker -v /my/own/var-lib-docker:/var/lib/docker -d docker:dind
```

The `-v /my/own/var-lib-docker:/var/lib/docker` part of the command mounts the `/my/own/var-lib-docker` directory from the underlying host system as `/var/lib/docker` inside the container, where Docker by default will write its data files.